# Most optimal way to fill grid with 1 type Tetromino

Tags: grid, pascal, packaging, fill, tetris

I need to fill a grid with variable X (X is between 2 and 7) and Y (Y is lower then 30) with a predefined shape, in this case a T Tetromino (the block with a row of three blocks with one added below the center).

The Tetromino can rotate in all 4 directions.

Can someone get me started?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not the site to come to when you have no idea how to even get started on your task. This is a site for asking *specific* questions of *general* interest. You'll need to work on your problem yourself until you get stuck. If the part you're stuck on is a *programming* question, then come back here and ask. However, it seems you don't have a programming problem; you have a *geometry* problem. (Also, when X=2, it's impossible to fill a grid with that shape of tetromino, so you'll have to figure out what your real requirements are, too.)

Comment: In addition to above, you need to work out what "fill" means in the case where you cannot get that shape Tetromino to perfectly fill your rectangle.